# Webapp for counting out calendar days?

Tags: calendar

Is there a webapp in which I can input something like `"six months and two weeks from now"` and get back a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

[image: For example:]